# Is my fusion drive supposed to show as two different volumes in Disk Utility? (It shows just one in Finder)

Tags: macos, hard-drive

After a time machine migration from an old iMac (non-fusion drive) to my new iMac (Fusion Drive), I noticed that in Disk Utility, my Fusion drive lists two volumes: "Macintosh HD" and "Macintosh HD - Data". In Finder, I just see "Macintosh HD". Is my drive split or is this normal behavior in Disk Utility?

[image: Disk Utility and "About This Mac - Storage"]

[image: terminal diskutil list]

Answer (score 2):

This is normal for all Catalina system/boot volume layouts independent of the number of physical disks involved.

The various main partitions (here disk0s2 & disk1s2) of the single physical disks of a Fusion Drive are combined as physical stores to one container: disk2. The predecessor (CoreStorage) did the same.

The whole container (here disk2) is divided into various APFS volumes with different roles: Preboot, Recovery, VM, Data and System. Each volume can be enlarged or shrunk dynamically.

The last two are combined in one APFS volume group.

You get all available APFS volume groups by entering `diskutil ap listVolumeGroups`.

The system volume (role: System, name: Macintosh HD, device: disk2s5) is mounted read-only. The necessary read-write data volume (role: Data, name: Macintosh HD – Data, device: disk2s1) is mounted to /System/Volumes/Data.

By default various folders of the Data volume are firmlinked to various folders of the System volume. They are needed to add user installed apps/binaries/frameworks etc. and user content (which requires a r/w volume) in a transparent way. The list of a all current firmlinks is available at */usr/share/firmlinks*.

The two devices in the APFS volume group (disk2s1 & disk2s5) mustn't be confused with the two physical devices (disk0 & disk1). Both APFS volumes may partially reside on both physical disks.

At least the APFS volumes with the roles Data and System are shown as separate devices in Disk Utiliy. I expect the volumes with the roles USER, Undefined and Installer (which don't exist in the standard partition scheme) to be also shown in Disk Utility – I haven't tested this though.

Further reading and pics of the various stages of Catalina APFS volume schemes:

1. [macOS Catalina Boot Volume Layout](https://eclecticlight.co/2019/10/08/macos-catalina-boot-volume-layout/)
2. [Working with APFS Volume Groups](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc5/working-apfs-volume-groups)